# Inconsistent web traffic

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I have this client who was having a big deal of traffic until December 31 2016. On January 1 (exactly that day), the site took a dive, and never recovered from it. This drop on traffic seems to be related to Android. According to some SEO guy they have, it's related to Analytics not parsing traffic from Android's direct search (I mean when you search Google on an Android device without even opening Chrome).

However, I took a look to Analytics on my client's request and I noticed that there are 2 patterns:

1. **Android traffic dropped**, but more or less in the same proportion
   than all traffic
2. **Traffic is tremendously inconsistent.** The plot literally looks like a roller coaster: 1 day with a peek, another day with a dive. Please note that before January 1 2017, traffic was quite stable (around 600 visitors a day). Now it may go from 50 to 700.

On top of the above, the site has a great deal of CPC traffic (GoogleAds and FB) but **both paid and organic traffic is consistent with the drop**, so at first I figured the site had some kind of technical issue. I monitored it closely for last 10 days, and **logs show no downtime on server**, thus I have no idea what's going on, only that **something happened on January 1st 2017** .

**Any idea on what could be going on? Is there any word on Google changing something on that date?**

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is an about a specific event.   It is not likely to be relevant to a large number of websites

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the search updates thread for January on WebmasterWorld: https://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4830556.htm  they track changes to Google that effect websites.